# Chrome App's <webview>.find method is undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

[The document](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-find) says that `<webview>` tag has a feature to initiate in-page text search since Chrome 35:

```
<webview>.find(string searchText, FindOptions options, function callback)
```

...but I found the method is `undefined` in my environment.

I'm using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

I have "webview" permission in my manifest, and other webview tag methods like back/forward/reload/clearData are working fine.

I also found that my webview is lacking some methods like getZoom/setZoom(which should be available since Chrome 36).

Do I need a special permission on my manifest to enable these features, or is this an error on the document side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's a documentation issue.

`webview.find` isn't on Stable Channel yet (see https://codereview.chromium.org/414803003)

You may want to try it out with Chrome Canary though (http://chrome.com/canary) since it works there.

Comment: Thank you for your information! I'll try Canary for now to see how it works and wait until it comes to the stable channel...